# Resize a Button JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx, resize, size

i have a question about a JavaFx Button.
In the following code i add a Button into a HBox.

```
ivTriangleImg.setFitHeight(16);
ivTriangleImg.setFitWidth(16);
ivTriangleImg.setRotate(iRotateCoord1);
btnTriangle.setGraphic(ivTriangleImg);
btnTriangle.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green;");
addComponentToBox(btnTriangle);
```

The Button gets a Graphic -> The Graphic is a transparent triangle with the Size of 16x16 pixels.
The Problem is, that the Button doesn't have the Size 16x16 it is so much more. How can i get the Button smaller and the Pictur must have the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added your Code, it works very fine. I made it a little bit different:

```
        btnTriangle.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;-fx-padding:0;-fx-background-size:0;");
```

Answer (score 4):

For JavaFX 8 use

```
btnTriangle.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
```

For JavaFX 2 use

```
btnTriangle.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0;");
```

However you can directly put the image view to the scene rather than setting it to the button's graphic, and add listeners you want:

```
ivTriangleImg.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. The problem is, that there is no Function like setPadding for the btnTriangle...
I user JavaFX 7